# Can I connect to SQL Server 2012 by sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

First I'm trying to write a csv file to desktop then I'm trying to connect to the SQL Server database but I get error which says:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error message.  I think the SQLCMD is trying to write to your desktop.  It does not know if it is a file or directory.  It is stating you do not have rights to create the file.

Try changing the output file to "c:\temp\test.txt" assuming there is a temp directory and everyone has rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command as follow if it support windows authentication login:

```
sqlcmd -S "yourServerName"
```